# Detecting Rectangles that share an edge

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a depth image from above of 4 containers, each with a different number of sub-compartments. I need to find an outline of the outside edge of each of the four containers.

I have thresholded the image and obtained an outline of the containers but since they share an edge, they are grouped together. How can I trace the outside edge of each container (or automatically split the contours in the correct spots using OpenCV?

```py
depth_img = np.load(depth)
depth_thresh = cv2.threshold(depth_img, 1200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
depth_close = cv2.morphologyEx(depth_thresh.astype(np.uint8), cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5,5),np.uint8))
depth_cnts = cv2.findContours(depth_close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
depth_cnts = imutils.grab_contours(depth_cnts)
for c in depth_cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(depth_img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01*peri, True)
    for pt in approx:
        cv2.circle(depth_contours, (pt[0][0],pt[0][1]),5,colors,-1)
```

See Images Below

Results:
[Original depth image and results of thresholding and countour approx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GilAW.png)

Desired Results: [Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZllGK.png)

Comment: Could you please provide some original input image(s), and the expected output maybe by manually marking the container(s) you want to have (do you [also] want the four/eight single containers top left / bottom right)? Nevertheless, a first idea would be to have closer look at the `hierarchy` option of [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0).

Comment: @HansHirse The original image is found at the link provided below the code. I've added an image of what the results should be. Either outlining the 4 large containers works or outlining the individual sub-compartments works too.

Comment: Are the containers always approximately the same size?

Comment: @CrisLuengo They are exactly the same size, just appear different depending on how far off center they are

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method :

1 ) - Detect lines using Hough lines probabilistic  or LSD
 2 ) - create some rules to merge those lines
 3 ) - compute intersections.
 4 ) - deduce rectangle corners.

Or use some  rotation/scale invariant edge based template matching .